# Selecting h.264 produces black video

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have a stop motion video with an audio track. When I select h.264 codec I get a black video with the audio. When I choose mpeg4 codec it works. Also, jpeg-raw produces the video but no audio.

What do I need to configure so h.264 codec works. Do I need to install the codec? I'm running windows 10.